# Getting the max array and converting it into 2x2 array in C

Tags: arrays, c, max

I am trying to divide a 2d array into regions and get a representative from each of the region by getting the maximum in it.

For example:

12 14 | **32** 9
19 **24** | 3 4
11 **26** | 3 **8**
13 24 | 7 5

into:

**24** **32**
**26** **8**

How to modify the code to get the max of each region?

```
int main() {
    int disp[4][4] = {{12,14,32,9},
                     {19,24,3,4},
                     {11,26,3,8},
                     {13,24,7,5}};

    int quadrant_size=2;

    for(int x=0 ; x<N ; x+=quadrant_size){
        for(int y=0 ; y<N ; y+=quadrant_size){
            for(int i=x ; i<x+quadrant_size ; i++){
                for(int j=y ; j<y+quadrant_size ; j++){
                    printf("%d ",disp[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, you are almost there: Just create a `mx` variable to find the maximum element in the region.

```
int main() { 
    int disp[4][4] = {{12,14,32,9}, 
                     {19,24,3,4},
                     {11,26,3,8},
                     {13,24,7,5}};
    int quadrant_size=2;
    int N = 4;

    for(int x=0 ; x<N ; x+=quadrant_size){
      for(int y=0 ; y<N ; y+=quadrant_size){
        int mx = dist[x][y];
        for(int i=x ; i<x+quadrant_size ; i++){
            for(int j=y ; j<y+quadrant_size ; j++){
                if (disp[i][j] > mx) {
                    mx = disp[i][j];
                }
            } 
        } 
        printf("%d ", mx); 
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to initialize `int mx = disp[x][y];` in case the elements in the quadrant are all less than 0.